# Repeating Alarm in Android Monthly

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am Having Some issues while setting a Repeating Alarm which shall trigger on a particular Date(Entered by user) for every month or every two month.
So far, I am using service for notification, BroadcastReceiver along with pending Intent. What i am unable to understand is:

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30*month, pendingIntent);
```

How can we set the function here and how is that going to affect the battery life and is there any other things( such as storing date in database and only call it when something triggers?) etc..
1.Notification Service Extending service

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        // Getting Notification Service
        mManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(
                        this.getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        /*
         * When the user taps the notification we have to show the Home Screen
         * of our App, this job can be done with the help of the following
         * Intent.
         */
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), com.expandablelistItems.demo.adapter.DynamicActivity.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Payment of your demoReminder", System.currentTimeMillis());

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this.getApplicationContext(),
                "demo", "Payment of your demoReminder",
                pendingNotificationIntent);

        mManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

2. Method for repeatation

```
if  (current_Month == Calendar.FEBRUARY){//for feburary month)
            GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();    
            if(cal.isLeapYear(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))){//for leap year feburary month  
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 29*month, pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "februry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            else{ //for non leap year feburary month
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "feb", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 28*month, pendingIntent);
            }
        }
```

and this is the broadcast receiver

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // When our Alaram time is triggered , this method will be excuted (onReceive)
    // We're invoking a service in this method which shows Notification to the User
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
     context.startService(myIntent);
   }
```

Where notificationService is the first code extending service

Comment: Don't you think your alarm will be off if your device is switched off atleast once in a month?

Comment: @Kedarnath nope. I have  retrieved it on boot via broadcast receiver

Comment: That's good, but then also I suggest you to use alternative ways since one month is long period of time.

Comment: Exactly @Kedarnath. This method will certainly drain the battery. I will find a solution from your method too. But i want this method work too. so, I am waiting for some explainations.

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid using `SetRepeating` with an interval of 30 days for two reasons:

1. It won't be repeating on the same day of every month (also might skip a month potentially).
2. Since API 19 `SetRepeating` is inexact and will function like `SetInexactRepeating` which means potentially shifting the alarm as much as a whole interval duration (up to 30 days in your case).
   As mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time
>   
>   As long as you want the alarm to trigger on the exact day you should use `set(int, long, PendingIntent)` and calculate next alarm after every instance.

Comment: You are right @Alex. I am searching for alternatives as it might drain the battery life bro. So, I am thinking of something like flight mode in mobiles. if the system date equals targetted date, then maybe flight mode can be made off and alarm can be triggered .. something like that. I don't know how to achieve it. You are certainly right though. Running services for a month is not good

Comment: @Bishal I can understand your worries yet setting an alarm has no direct consequence to battery life (it does if the alarm rate becomes substantial, every minute for example). Also as long as you don't set the wakeup flag it will preserve even more of that precious battery. Here's the official guide, it might help: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: umm. I think i am more clear than before. Let me implement this , and i will come with battery manipulation of different methods. you definately gave me one method of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Basically,

- You can to initialize pendigIntent to the specific Intent which will receive the Alarm and trigger intended action.
- AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30*month - specifies the number of months(1month/2months) * 30 * daily interval(i.e 24 hr)
- You can create a class like AlarmReceiver which will be having onReceive() method in which you can perform your action.

### **Regarding Battery life and other ways:**

One of the ways is using ScheduleThreadExecutor class but which runs number of  threads and  using AlarmManager we can improve performance.

Instead of creating instance of AlarmManager you can use **Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)** as this is the system service.
Which will optimize memory usage and battery life.

One more thing  you can use **setInexactRepeating** instead of setRepeating, those alarms are more power-efficient

For detailed info you can visit to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: your method seems more convincing. Are you intending to say me making a class called alarmReceiver extending BroadcastReceiver and doing things like inside it. I do have done it.  can you give me some more details on it

Comment: Right! and in the class where you want to add AlarmManager , You have to create an instance of Intent  for AlarmReceiver Class. You have to pass this intent to the pendingIntent and then you can use setInexactRepeating to trigger alarm.I think it would be sufficient.

Comment: You would never instantiate `AlarmManager` but get it from calling `alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);`. Also `SetInexactRepeating` has nothing to do with API 19 it was introduced in API 3

Comment: Yep @Alex.F You are correct because in my level of understanding, setexactRepeating deals with triggering in exact time whereas setInexactRepeating can get delayed and triggerring can vary. Correct me if i am wrong here

Answer (score 0):

While an Alarm will be vanished if your device is turned off. I suggest you to use an alternet way for triggering an action after a long period(like one month). Try Reminder or Calendar Events.

Please check the [Reminder's Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21822720/3330969)

Please check the [Calendar's Event Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19160815/3330969)